# Sorting a char array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, char

How would I sort a char array in Java? I know I can use java.util.Arrays.sort(), but if I manually want to sort it? Using bubble sort or something?

Notice the string is "cab", the sorted result should be "abc". I don't know how to sort this, i know how to sort integers, but i don't know how to sort char arrays.

Here's my code:

```
String s1 = "cab";
char[] arr;
arr = s1.toCharArray();

//Could use
//java.util.Arrays.sort(arr);
//But want to do it manually using something like bubble sort

s1 = new String(arr);
```

Comment: do you need to use bubble sort for your assignment?

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you're asking. Are you asking how to [write a bubble sort algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832765/whats-a-bubble-sort)? Or are you asking how to access the individual items within an array?

Comment: if you know how to sort an integer array, then do the same but change the type from int to char and the comparison method (`if char1 < char2 ` thing).

Comment: for your character sorting, from '*' and '/' which one you want to come first

Answer (score 3):

characters can be directly compared as the comparison operators are overloaded. w>q i.e

```
arr[1]>arr[0]
```

is valid and gives true. So just treat them like integers in the bubble sort algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

> Using bubble sort or something?

Yes, a bubble sort would work.  Or you could use any one of the other well-known sort algorithms; e.g. as listed in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) ... or any good textbook on data structures and algorithms.

(But no, I'm not going to code this for you.)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea weather this solution is the best way, and to be honest I don't think it is.

But I'v made a little piece of code which sorts an array in the following steps:

Make a for loop that goes from 0 to `array.size() * array.size()`.

Make a index variable (int) which is 0 out side the loop

in the loop add a try catch and catch OutOfBoundsException, in the catch set index to 0.

In the try you get 'index' of your array,

```
char c = array[index]
```

And compare to index +1

```
  c.compareTo(array[index +1])
```

If that's a positive number >0 you switch the two items' positions **array[index]** and **array[index + 1]**

If it doesn't make sense to you I can provide a code sample, but not before 2 hours from now, approximately..

This is what I meant:

```
public static ArrayList<mContact> SortByName(ArrayList<mContact> arr)
{
int i = 0;
    for (int o = 0; o < arr.size() * arr.size(); o++)
    {
        try
        {
            int c = arr.get(i).getName().compareTo(arr.get(i + 1).getName());
            if (c > 0)
            {
                mContact con = new mContact(arr.get(i).getName());

                arr.get(i).setName(arr.get(i+1).getName());

                arr.get(i+1).setName(con.getName());

            }
            i++;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

That sorts the List by the contacts Name in ascending order.

The compareTo Method returns a integer that represents the diffrence of the two strings. and 0 if they are the same!

Comment: Yes sample code would be helpful.

Comment: What I wrote works for string, you might optimize it a lot using Sesha H's answer also

Answer (score 0):

You can compare ASCII values of each of the characters or convert each of the to int using parseInt and compare their values.